# angular-masonry directive showing images in only one column

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, masonry

Trying to use the angular-masonry directive by passy (https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry)

It's showing the images in one column, rather than the grid layout.  Any help would be appreciated!

My html

```
<div class="container">
  <div masonry>
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="brick in bricks">
        <img ng-src="{{ brick.picUrl }}" alt="A masonry brick">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.masonry-brick { 
    width: 25%; 
    margin: 0.1em;
}

.masonry-brick img { 
    width:100%; 
}
```

Now, if I include float: left styling in the .masonry-brick class, then it kind of works, but with major gaps.  Also, for some reason my masonry-options aren't working. If I was to add transitionDuration:

```
<div class="container">
  <div masonry="{ transitionDuration: '0.4s' }">
    <div class="masonry-brick" ng-repeat="brick in bricks">
      <img ng-src="{{ brick.picUrl }}" alt="A masonry brick">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It shows no change in how the images load. However, angular-masonry is installed correctly and all the files are included and injected correctly.  I am getting no errors in that regard.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Load jquery before loading angularjs. Also use newer version of masonry.

Comment: If masonry is not working at all then you can also use angular-deckgrid masonry like directive.

Comment: I'm using version .11 of angular-masonry and version 3.2 of masonry.  I believe they are the most current.  My file loading is in the correct order.  Another strange thing is that the demo here, http://www.directiv.es/angular-masonry, also seems to have stopped working.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I'll take a look at angular-deckgrid as well

Comment: Have you loaded jquery before angular?

Comment: Yes I have.  Does the directiv.es example work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I'm using `ng-show` or `ng-hid`e in or within the masonry div block. Make sure you add `reload-on-show` to the div tag that uses ng-show or ng-hide.